# CppUnit / undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, cppunit

This is my first post, so please forgive me smaller mistakes.

For programming techniques lab in university, we have to test a self-written program with the tool `CppUnit`. 
For this, I excluded the `Exercise8.cpp`, which was my former main-function. No the compiler should use the `WinMain.cpp` from the `CppUnit`, but this doesn't work. 
How could I tell my compiler, which main-function it have to use?
(Working with Win8/64bit, Eclipse, CppUnit)!
[My actual workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmqWl.jpg)

Comment: The question is missing some necessary infos. What is the exact name of the main function in Exercise8.cpp. Is it "main" or "WinMain"?

Comment: @MartinSchlott by looking at link to his workspace, seems it is coming from mingw/main..

Comment: I fixed it by my self.
Two ways to fix it:
Put the WinMain.cpp of the CppUnit in your src-folder and exclude the existing exercise8.cpp from build.
or
Go to "Project Properties”, “C/C++ General | Paths and symbols” and add “test” as source folder

So it was a linker-problem, and my compiler didn't know he also had to use the "test" folder for building.